# Web page not resizing on mobile

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap, resize, html

I have a problem with my web page not wanting to resize according to a phone's width...at least not the whole page.

The example of the page can be seen at: http://sibincic.bobr.si/index_table.html
If I try it on an HTC Desire which has a resolution of 480x800 it resizes it but not all the way.

If anyone has any ideas what I should do please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

You must use that sentence in  section, and use bootstrap responsive CSS.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Note that with Bootstrap 3 you only need the meta tag: http://getbootstrap.com/css/